# Can I hold both work permit and business visa for germany?

Tags: visas, business-travel, work-permit

I already have a work permit for Germany. But I would like to know if I can apply for a business visa for a short visit?

Comment: Why would you need a business visa if you already have a work permit?

Comment: @jpatokal , I have only work permit. But no Visa yet. If I go in work permit for short duration, on-site salary is very low for that month. So thinking to go in business visa

Comment: @Alpha2 how is having a business visa going to affect your salary?

Comment: @ChrisH   By calculating all the expenses for one month in on-site, my offshore salary is much more than that. So as per my organisation, if i go in business visa i wont get on-site salary. So i will get my Offshore salary

Comment: @Alpha2 which type of work permit do you have? I'm not sure if it's relevant (I have a suspicion the answer will be "no, you can't" regardless), but it's good information to include in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is first of all not quite clear what you are asking about, but no matter how we guess or interpret the details, the answer is no.

Germany has not been issuing work permits since 2004, so what you have (and call a work permit) must be a residence permit. Residence permits may or may not allow the holder to work. If you already have a residence permit, this permit already gives you more rights in Germany and the same rights as a short-stay visa in all other Schengen countries, so for immigration purposes, there will be absolutely no point in issuing you a new, additional visa.

It is not obviously clear from your question why your salary depends on the immigration status, but that is something you will have to clarify with your employer. German authorities won't issue you a redundant visa, just because your employer in that case will allegedly pay better.